# Nothing happens with JavaScript form submission

Tags: javascript, forms

Can anybody tell me Why I click on button to submit form -> it works,  but when I use javascript to auto submit -> it failed ?

I have this form on aaa.com, it submit to bbb.com/result.jsp (another domain)

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm " method="post" action="www.bbb.com/result.jsp">
<input name="var01" value="var01 ">
<input name="var02" value="var02 ">
 <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search">
</form>
```

Manually click on Search button, result.jsp works fine.

When I added following script, result.jsp page doesn’t work

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: What messages do your browser's console report?

Comment: Maybe document.getElementById("myForm")...

Comment: My problem is that ("myForm").submit() doesn't tell the event action (or which submit button) should be performed? How can I trigger submit button when submit form with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form has `id="myForm"` but your JavaScript is looking for `myform`. IDs are case-sensitive.

[Changing that](http://jsbin.com/ecafod/2/edit) makes it work.

Comment: Hi, I change like this: document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
But still the result.jsp page reject to process

Comment: If the `result.jsp` page is rejecting it, then it has something to do with what `result.jsp` is looking for … and you haven't shared its code with us. That said, the submit button won't be successful if you don't use it to submit the form, so change `result.jsp` so it doesn't look for `searchButton` in the submitted data.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember, the HTML id attribute is case-sensitive. You are calling the `.submit()` method on `myform` while your form id is `myForm`.